# android : using Tab view with dynamic fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have created an application which contains tab view and dynamic fragments concepts. the code was earlier working fine when when i was switching to different activity on pressing the tabs , but when i converted it to work for fragments, dushhhh.I know working on fragments and activity is two different things , but logic is the same just few changes here   there , Here is the code .

```
The main layout is  "activity_main.xml" 

    <TabHost 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

I have used two fragments to switch through when  user presses any of the tab : 
    one of the fragments layout is  "googleMap.xml":

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/google_map"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="MAP"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

the second fragment is : "friends_list.xml"

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewFriends"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="friends list will appear here" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/friends_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The main activity is  : "MainActivity.java" :

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

    import com.example.friendsfinder.R;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setTabContent();

        }

        private void setTabContent() {
            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);


            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map",
                            getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    MapFragment.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("friends list").setIndicator("Friends List",
                            getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    FriendsListFragment.class, null);


        }
    }
```

The first fragment file is  "FriendsListFragment.java" :

```
    import com.example.friendsfinder.R;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class FriendsListFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list, container,false);


            return view;
        }

    }
```

Second fragment file is : "MapFragment.java" :

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_map, container,false);

            return view;

        }

    }
```

The error that is coming is this : Logcat entries are :

```
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.friendsfinder/com.webonise.friendsfinder.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TabHost
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TabHost
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at com.webonise.friendsfinder.MainActivity.setTabContent(MainActivity.java:22)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at com.webonise.friendsfinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-19 19:26:40.767: E/AndroidRuntime(28679):    ... 11 more
09-19 19:26:51.617: I/Process(28679): Sending signal. PID: 28679 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast a TabHost to FragmentTabHost

try this

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost >
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a class cast excption in your main activity

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

findviewbyid(android.R.id.tabhost);   android.R.id.tabhost???? check this line and you will not get this error.

Comment: No that is working fine , the problem was with the xml file  .The above provided solution is correct . I was using "<TabHost " instead of "<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost".Thankyou anyway.